# Parameterized SQL Values syntax issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameterized-query

I'm not sure what the issue is but my code looks like:

```
function() {
string sqltext2;
sqltext2 = "INSERT into myTable";
SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(sqltext2, MyConnection2);

if (cond1) {

    sqltext2 = sqltext2 + "SELECT" + "@initOwnerFirstName" + "," + "@ownerFirstName"  + "UNION ALL ";
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@initOwnerFirstName";
    param.Value = initOwnerFirstName;
    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
    param2.ParameterName = "@ownerFirstName";
    param2.Value = owner.FirstName;
    myCommand2.Parameters.Add(param);
    myCommand2.Parameters.Add(param2);
```

I'm completely new with parameterized SQL but the syntax seems right to me. The error I keep getting is:

Must declare the scalar variable "@initOwnerFirstName".
The reason I'm writing the statement like that is because I intend to have multiple other if statements that will add to the SQLtext

EDIT: Here is the full part of the code after the if statement since my syntax makes little sense without the other variables. This is cleaned up after what JYelton suggested but I'm still getting the same error.

```
sqltext2 = sqltext2 + "SELECT" + "'" + currentUserId2 + "'," + "'" +  owner.Id.ToString() + "'," + "'" + DateTime.Now + "'," + "'FirstName', @initOwnerFirstName, @ownerFirstName UNION ALL ";
myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("initOwnerFirstName", initOwner.FirstName);
myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("OwnerFirstName", owner.FirstName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem could be that you are concatenating your strings without spaces.  You don't need to concatenate either.  See my update below:

```
function() {
string sqltext2;
sqltext2 = "INSERT into dbo.OwnerChanges ";
SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(sqltext2, MyConnection2);

if (cond1) {
    //no concatenating
    sqltext2 = sqltext2 + " SELECT @initOwnerFirstName , @ownerFirstName UNION ALL ";
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@initOwnerFirstName";
    param.Value = initOwnerFirstName;
    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
    param2.ParameterName = "@ownerFirstName";
    param2.Value = owner.FirstName;
    myCommand2.Parameters.Add(param);
    myCommand2.Parameters.Add(param2);
```

I'm not sure what the rest of your code does but I suspect you are leaving a trailing `UNION ALL` at the end of all that.  You could probably benefit by just putting each sub query into an array and using [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) on them.

**UPDATE:**

I think I see the issue.  You need to update CommandText and not the original string.  So change this:

```
sqltext2 = sqltext2 + " SELECT @initOwnerFirstName , @ownerFirstName UNION ALL ";
```

to this:

`myCommand2.CommandText= sqltext2 + " SELECT @initOwnerFirstName , @ownerFirstName UNION ALL ";`

Comment: Well the reason I have the concatenations is that there are other variables I'm giving it that are not set to parameters that I didn't include. I combined them but there is still that same error. The UNION ALL is truncated at the end as well.

Comment: @Abe agreed, the OP's query string is modified after it is assigned to `myCommand2`. @Aeonstrife: That causes the parameters to be "missing" when it is executed, and the error "must declare scalar variable..." to occur.

Comment: @Aeonstrife - Always declare column names when creating insert statements. If you don't do this your code will be brittle. ie adding a field to the db is enough to break it.

Comment: Ok that seems to have worked. However, since the sql command is executed at the end of a bunch of if statements, the sqltext can be updated at each if statement. Would it be better if it was like:

`myCommand2.CommandText = myCommand2.CommandText + "SELECT" + "'" + currentUserId2 + "'," + "'" + owner.Id.ToString() + "'," + "'" + DateTime.Now + "'," + "'FirstName', @initOwnerFirstName, @ownerFirstName UNION ALL ";
`

Comment: @Aeonstrife: Update the string through the if statements as normal, but don't assign the string to the `myCommand2` until just before you execute it. You can add parameters to the query before you actually assign the query string, but be aware that any parameters declared in the query string must have a matching `Parameters.Add[WithValue]()`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.
@whosrdaddy:
Which part? The variables that aren't parameterized aren't values that can be altered.

Comment: maybe, but it's a code smell. Today it's an unalterable field but maybe tomorrow it will be. You are using parameters, which is good, why not go the whole mile? (makes the code more readable to IMHO)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how parameterized queries work:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
{
    using SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO mytable
            (initOwnerFirstName, ownerFirstName)
            VALUES (@initOwnerFirstName, @ownerFirstName);";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("initOwnerFirstName", initOwner.FirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ownerFirstName", owner.FirstName);
        // ... execute query
    }
}
```

It looks like you are inserting into `myTable` the results of a `SELECT` statement, but you are trying to pass parameters where the column names should go. The Parameter will replace the `@variablename` with the value, thus: Parameters are for the values, not the column names.

For multiple values, use parenthesis to specify the set, separated by commas:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES ("a", "b"), ("c", "d"), ("e", "f");
```

You can modify the query string appropriately to fit this syntax.

More information: [SQL Insert Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h54fa37c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This is for SQL Server not MySQL

Comment: MySQL? The question says sql-server

Comment: @Abe @ErikE Sorry, my mistake: link and link text corrected. However the syntax is the same.

Comment: Well the reason I was using Insert SELECT UNION ALL was because I wanted to add more to the command in future If statements. I wasn't specifying columns because I had a value for each column in the table. That direction makes sense to me but since I'm using different syntax for the insert it doesn't translate properly. The error doesn't make sense to me because it says that it recognizes there is a variable but it's not declared, which it is clearly.

Comment: @Aeonstrife: Abe's update to his answer will help you out, check it out.